# What is the broadcasting order here?

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following:

```
polygons = np.array([
       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[3, 2],
        [2, 2],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 3]]])

sort_idx = np.array([
       [2, 0, 1, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 3]])

polygons[sort_idx]  #< The problematic part
```

The expected output is:

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 3]]])
```

I expect `polygons[sort_idx]` to return the "sorted" rows of `polygons`, with the sorting order given by the values in `sort_idx`.
`polygons[0][sorted_idx[0]]` (and the equivalent for `[1]`) give the correct values, but running `polygons[sort_idx]` raises:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

I estimate the issue is connected to me not understanding something of how the operation is broadcasted, but I don't really know what to search for or how to phrase the question. I saw similar questions recommending to use `np.take()` or `polygons[sort_idx,...]`, but both raise the same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.take_along_axis`:

```
np.take_along_axis(polygons, sort_idx[..., None], 1)
Out[]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`take_along_axis` is supposed to 'streamline' indexing that we had to do (and still can do) with:

```
In [233]: polygons[np.arange(2)[:,None], sort_idx]
Out[233]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 4],
        [2, 3]]])
```

The first dimension index is (2,1), and then second (2,4), which broadcast together to select (2,4) in the first 2 dimensions (and the last dimension unchanged).

The values of `sort_idx` are meant to apply to the 2nd axis, the size 4 one.  `polygons[sort_idx]` applies them to the first, size 2, dimension, hence the error.

Using slice for the first dimension returns too many values, a block.  We want something more like a diagonal:

```
In [235]: polygons[:, sort_idx,:].shape
Out[235]: (2, 2, 4, 2)
```

So yes, it is a `broadcasting` issue.  When using multiple indexing arrays, we want to think about how they `broadcast` against each other.  Same rules as for operators apply.

```
In [236]: np.array([10,100])[:,None]* sort_idx
Out[236]: 
array([[ 20,   0,  10,  30],
       [100,   0, 200, 300]])
```

Comment: Thank you *very* much for the explanation, I had never thought of the effect of broadcasting for index arrays, this really helps!